# Find formulas for the entires of $M^n$ ($n\ge0$) (Eigen Vector/Values)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need a little help with an eigen vector question,

The question

Let $M =\left|\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\
                           -36 & 13 \end{matrix}\right|$

Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer

The resulting matrix is a $2\times2$ matrix

What I got so Far

I found that there is one eigen value which is $7$ and I believe I found an eigen vector which is $\langle1,-6\rangle$ (Please double check)

However I'm confused as to what to do next

Can some please enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: That is correct, eigenvector should be $(1,6)$. So $M$ is not diagonalisable only one linearly independent eigenvector). You can find the Jordan Normal form of $M$ instead and use that.